# Cómo mostrar un campo de una foreign key ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Tengo este modelo Productor:

```
class Productor(ModeloBase):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    es_productor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    razon_social = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    numero_fiscal = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True)
```

Y lo que me interesa sería poder mostrar en el form los campos del User(username, first_name, last_name y email), pero no sé cómo hacerlo. Estuve leyendo esta [documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/modelforms/) pero no encontré nada relacionado a lo que estoy buscando. Este es el formulario que tengo hecho hasta ahora:

```
class ProductorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Productor
        fields = [
            'user',
            'razon_social',
            'numero_fiscal',
            'es_productor'
        ]
        widgets = {
            'user': forms.Select(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Razón social',
                'style': 'font-size: 1.0rem; color: black'
            }),
            'razon_social': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Razón social',
                'style': 'font-size: 1.0rem; color: black'
            }),
            'numero_fiscal': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'Número fiscal',
                'style': 'font-size: 1.0rem; color: black'
            }),
            'es_productor': forms.CheckboxInput(),
        }
        labels = {
            'razon_social': 'Razón social',
            'numero_fiscal': 'Número fiscal',
            'es_productor': 'Es productor',
        }
```

Desde ya muchas gracias, y avísenme si es que necesitan más información del código o de lo que quiero hacer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalmente lo que yo hago es lo siguiente: en el `forms` hago referencia a los campos de `User` de forma genérica, guardando los datos del user que correspondan en el `save` del formulario:

```
class ProductorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(...)
    last_name = forms.CharField(...)
    email = forms.EmailField(...)

    class Meta:
        model = Productor
        fields = [
            'user',
            'razon_social',
            'numero_fiscal',
            'es_productor'
        ]
  
    def save(self, commit=True):
        productor = super().save(commit=True)
        productor.user.first_name = first_name
        productor.user.last_name = last_name
        productor.user.email = email
        productor.user.save()

        return productor
```

Luego en el `views` puedes definir los campos iniciales del formulario, por ejemplo:

```
from django.views.generic

class ProductorUpdate(generic.UpdateView):
    model = Productor
    form_class = ProductorForm
    ...

    def get_initial():
        initial = super().get_initial()
        user = self.get_object().user
        initial.update({
            first_name = user.first_name,
            last_name = user.last_name,
            email = user.email
        })
        return initial
```